# UrlFetchApp. Отправка массива в другой веб-сервис

Tags: google-apps-script

Пытаюсь отправить вот такой массив себе на сервер:

```
var lead_fields = {
    fields:{
      'NAME': 'Не указано'
    },
  };
```

На сервере получаю вот что:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ожидаю переменную `fields` не как строку, а как массив. Вот код:

```
var lead_fields = {
    fields:{
      'NAME': 'Не указано'
    },
  };
var url = "https://ags.website/test.php";
  var lead_options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'payload' : lead_fields 
  };
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, lead_options);
```

Как получить переменную `fields` в виде массива?

Answer (score 0):

Как известно, при передаче данных в веб используется определенный тип контента [развиться можно тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) .

В данном топике затрагивается вопрос [What is the difference between application/json and application/x-www-form-urlencoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870523)

Разумно предположить, что ответ кроется где-то в документации. Напрмиер, тут [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app).

### Отправляем `contentType : application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

```
// Make a POST request with form data.
var resumeBlob = Utilities.newBlob('Hire me!', 'text/plain', 'resume.txt');
var formData = {
  'name': 'Bob Smith',
  'email': 'bob@example.com',
  'resume': resumeBlob
};
// Because payload is a JavaScript object, it will be interpreted as
// as form data. (No need to specify contentType; it will automatically
// default to either 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
// or 'multipart/form-data')
var options = {
  'method' : 'post',
  'payload' : formData
};
UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', options);
```

### Отправляем `contentType : application/json`

```
// Make a POST request with a JSON payload.
var data = {
  'name': 'Bob Smith',
  'age': 35,
  'pets': ['fido', 'fluffy']
};
var options = {
  'method' : 'post',
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  // Convert the JavaScript object to a JSON string.
  'payload' : JSON.stringify(data)
};
UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', options);
```

### Решение

Для конкретного примера, вероятно, подойдет

```
var lead_fields = {
  fields:{
    'NAME': 'Не указано'
  },
};
var url = "https://ags.website/test.php";
var lead_options = {
  'method' : 'post',
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  'payload' : JSON.stringify(lead_fields) 
};
var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, lead_options);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
Документацию перечел, все равно сложные массивы передаются в виде строки. Вернее говоря, второй уровень массива передается в виде строки. То есть "дети" в массиве  передаются в виде JSON строки. "Родители" передаются как положено.
Обратите внимание на то, что в первом вашем примере массив передается простой, не с вложенными элементами. В вашем втором примере передача идет закодированной JSON строкой. Это не подходит, т.к сторонние веб сервисы такие данные не воспринимают. Решения пока так и не вижу.

Comment: @andrew_jackson, как-то сумбурно получилось. Добавил 3й пример, посмотрите.

Comment: @andrew_jackson, ну?